# "Cannot convert from method group to bool" And difference between "ReadToEnd" & "ReadToEndAsync" in C#

Tags: c#

This is my method. This "sr.ReadToEnd" gives an error. "Argument 1: Cannot covert from group method to bool". It suggest that "ReadToEnd" tchange to "ReadToEndAsync". But it also gives me the same error. I am novel to C#. SO I want to know,

What is group method?

Why this gives me that error?

What is the difference between "ReadToEnd" and "ReadToEndAsync"

```
<pre>
 private static void TestExceptionHandling()
    {
        StreamReader sr = null;
        try
        {
            sr = File.OpenText(@"E:\4th(Final) Year\LastSemester\SM\Alternatives1_2.docx");
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException FNF)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(FNF.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `sr.ReadToEnd()`

Comment: .docx is a binary file. You're not going to be able to read the contents of it this way. You need a library that understands the format.

Comment: But I tried after using .txt. But it doesn't work.

Comment: A text file will work, but a .docx file won't. That's like saying "my car's engine won't start, so I poured Coca Cola into the gas tank and it still didn't work." Of course it won't work, it's the wrong thing to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sr.ReadToEnd() and sr.ReadToEndAsync() are methods and you are using them as properties/variables that's why you are getting the error.

Coming to difference between them ReadToEnd is synchronous method runs on main thread and ReadToAsync is asynchronous runs on separate thread

Comment: What is the best method to use or when we can use those 2?

Comment: If you want run in background without blocking UI use Async which will run on separate thread

Comment: As its console application I don't think you need to worry about UI freezing

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually call the ReadToEnd method and write its return value.
Try replacing

```
Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd);
```

with

```
Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
```